# How to undo an extracted folder

Tags: extract, 7zip

I extracted a 7zip folder and I thought it would create a new folder to place all the files. However it spat out all the files into my Documents folder and now it is a total mess. Is there a way to undo the 7zip folder extraction or somehow delete all the newly extracted files in my Documents folder? It will be too much work to try and go through all of them. Please help, thanks!

Comment: As far as I know there is no repacking feature in 7zip or even gzip. You will need to use the **find** command, so I will post an answer and let us all know how you go.

Comment: The easy way is to use your unpacking tool to list the contents of the archive, save the results in a file, edit the file down to a list of filenames, then feed the filenames to `rm`, possibly using `xargs`.

Answer (score 0):

If we **assume** the date of extraction was 20th October;
`find ~/Documents -maxdepth 1 -type f -newermt 'Oct 20' ! -newermt 'Oct 21' -print`
After confirming these are the files you can delete them;
`find ~/Documents -maxdepth 1 -type f -newermt 'Oct 20' ! -newermt 'Oct 21' -delete`
Good Luck!

Comment: Will this work even if the date modified of the unpacked files is varying dates?

Edit: This did not list all the files because they do not have date modified dates from yesterday.

Comment: No but the date should be the same. If it's not that is a problem. Are you sure typing `ls -l` shows those files with **different** dates?

Comment: I tested on my 20.04 and the **mtime** shows all the various dates like you say, so not a good answer then. However the "Birth" date will be the date you unzipped. If you cd to Documents then pick a file and type `stat filename.extension` you will see all the different dates. Linux didn't used to have birth dates so it's new to me but hopefully someone knows how to modift this answer to work on the birth date.

Comment: Also to confirm your files birth date use `ls --time='birth' -l`